# How can i convert NSData to const uint8_t?or getting error while passing a NSData over Wifi

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, network-programming, wifi

i have a array with two strings:

```
NSArray *sendingArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"CAT",@"DOG",nil];
```

and i converted the array to NSData:

```
NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:sendingArray];
```

now i need to convert my `NSData(myData)` to `const uint8_t`

i am doing this code to send an array of values through Wifi network.

i send successfully a string over wifi using the below code(my string is "string").

```
 const uint8_t *message = (const uint8_t *)[string UTF8String]; 

    [_outStream write:bytes maxLength:len];
```

i wrote the below code to send NSData object but it got error.

code is:

```
const uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t)[myData bytes];//this line getting error.
    [_outStream write:bytes maxLength:len];
```

can i send my `NSData(myData)` through the above method without converting it to const uint8_t? if yes,please give me the code that i need to write.

or can any one tell me the way to convert my `NSData(myData)` to `const uint8_t`

Comment: You don't think it would be helpful for us to see the error you're getting?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
 const uint8_t *bytes = (const uint8_t*)[myData bytes];
 //                                   ^^ note the asterisk
```